# How to write Dictionary AND list to csv or .xlsx with python

Tags: python, excel, csv

New to SO and programming so TIA for any help.

I have a **dictionary** of cities and their corresponding country. 
I have a **list** of longitudes and latitudes for each city (scraped using Selenium).

In my current code, I can only write the latitudes and longitudes to a .csv file.

Is there anyway I can write the dictionary key (city) and the corresponding long_lat, so I know what city the long_lat belongs to?

Code:

```
import os, time, openpyxl, csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#IMPORT EXCEL FILE
print('opening workbook...')
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Data.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Missing']

d = {} #dictionary to contain city and corresponding country

#GRAB CITY AND COUNTRY FROM EXCEL
for row in range(2,5):
    country = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    city = sheet['C' + str(row)].value

    d[city] = country

lat_long_list = [['-24.211531', ' 151.902298'], ['-20.269600', ' 148.720535'], ['-43.805199', ' 172.966995']]


with open('csvPrintTest.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for coOrdinate in lat_long_list:
        writer.writerow([coOrdinate])

print('Done')
```

Desired Output when opening csv in Excel:

```
City         LatLong

Agnes Waters  ['-24.211531', '151.902298']
Airlie Beach  ['-20.269600', ' 148.720535']
Akaroa        ['-43.805199', ' 172.966995']
```

Comment: Depending what you want to do with the city name and the Lat/Long, you might want to look at the option of using Excel's ability to directly import data from a web page rather than having to do the scrape in python.

Comment: How do you know which city corresponds to each list element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `sheet` are in sync with your `lat_long_list`, create a `list` of `dict`:

```
lat_long_list = [['-24.211531', ' 151.902298'], ['-20.269600', ' 148.720535'], ['-43.805199', ' 172.966995']]

csv_data = []
for row in range(2,5):
    country = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    city = sheet['C' + str(row)].value
    i = row - 2
    csv_data.append({'city':city, 
                     'country':country, 
                     'lat':lat_long_list[i][0], 
                     'long':lat_long_list[i][1]
                    })

fieldnames = ['city', 'country', 'lat', 'long']
header = {'city':'City', 'country':'Country', 'lat':'Lat', 'long':'Long'}

with open('csvPrintTest.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(csv_data)
```

Comment: Yes the citys are in sync. This worked, i just had to change the = to : in the csv_data.append dictionary and header dictionary. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If your list is in the same sequence as rest of the data you can easily add it to your dictionary and then make a dataframe followed by df.to_csv('filename'). Hope it helps. Be very careful if the sequence is not the same as the rest of the lists in your dictionary.